# iOS Core Bluetooth app used like a Central doesn't work in background

Tags: ios, xcode, background, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I've an app that uses Core Bluetooth in foreground, everything is working fine. Now I'm trying to enable the background usage, I checked the correct options in Capabilities like the documentation says but the sync doesn't happen, only when I call the app to foreground again. Someone had this problem also? Should I implement more things like "State Preservation and Restoration"?

Just to be more clear, I'm using a specific UUID.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code?  How are you initiating the transfer in the background? Does the peripheral "notify/indicate" a characteristic?

Comment: What do you mean with "initiating the transfer in background"? I don't found nothing to do in Core Bluetooth documentation. I just start the scan when the app is opened and I was think that it was enough to work when the app goes to background. I will update de question with the start scan part.

Comment: You can scan to discover a peripheral - then you need to connect - then you either need to send data or receive data from a notify.   From your update - you are looking for a call to `didDiscoverPeripheral` in the background?

Comment: Be aware that if you specify multiple services to `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` that the peripheral must advertise **all** of the listed services - typically the peripheral will only advertise the main service and you can discover the rest once you connect

Comment: I'm doing this test with a known peripheral so the methods like scanForPeripheralsWithServices and didDiscoverPeripheral will not called.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.  The operation of Core Bluetooth central in the background is exactly the same as in the foreground - you either need to scan or have a connection and issue read/write (or receive notifications) with the appropriate delegate methods being called

Comment: Sorry about my english, I wanted to say with that is that I have a peripheral that I have connected before so I don't need to discovery the peripheral again. But it's not the problem. What I have understand with the documentation is that I just need to enable the option like a did e make sure I'm specifying one UUID. I'm doing that but the code isn't working in background.

Comment: If can retrieve the peripheral using `peripheralWithIdentifier` then you can issue a `connect` directly. Perhaps this will help - https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground you can change the UUID of the service it looks for to yours

Comment: I will take a look on that. Tks for your help @Paulw11